# Does a new CRM 2011 update rollup contains changes of previous rollups

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Suppose I find some necessary updates for my CRM 2011 On-Premise installation in UR7 and in UR14. Should I install both the rollups or installing UR14 only will cover all the changes of UR7 as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just install Rollup 14 as it will include Rollup 7.

You must be at [Rollup 6 before you can install Rollup 14](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2849744) (or Rollup 7):

> ou must have Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Update Rollup 6 (build 5.0.9690.1992) or a later version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 installed to apply this update rollup.

You cannot uninstall Rollup 6 as it makes non-reversible changes to the database.

Rollup 12, included in Rollup 14, includes changes to JavaScript and the DOM for multi-browser support which means certain UI customizations may break. I recommend thorough testing - if you have implemented any HTML or JavaScript - before upgrading to Rollup 12 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick. As far as I know, UR12 (also called Polaris) brings some new changes like new form design (like CRM 2013), async loading of JScript libraries. Problem arose with async loading of JScript libraries got fixed in UR15. So I should better go with UR15. Will I get new form designs automatically with this UR15 or do I need to do something to make them enable?

Comment: Yes, you do get Form changes with UR12. I recommend this excellent article on how to make CRM use the old forms after applying Rollup 12+: http://goo.gl/w9YrOZ. I normally recommend one behind the latest Rollup released for production systems (unless you must have something in the latest.) Since the latest is Rollup 16 therefore I recommend Rollup 15.

Comment: I have installed UR6 and UR14 on my CRM Server but still I am not able to see any changes in any of the entity forms. What am I missing here?

Comment: It is only going to apply to certain default forms and only if those forms don't have any custom JavaScript.